# Indefinite integral involving the Lambert W or product log function.

Tags: analysis, indefinite-integrals, lambert-w

How to calculate the integral

$\displaystyle \int \frac{1-x}{x W\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)} \, dx$ ?

I tried making a substitution but it doesn't seem to work.

Does this integral have a symbolic solution or a series expansion?

Comment: What is the original problem leading to the evaluation of such thing? The integral over (0,1) *can* be computed in explicit terms, given the relation with Gregory coefficients.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio The problem was about the integral $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x\ln\left(x\right)+1}$
 and its inverse. The integral in this question would be the inverse.

Comment: Hmm.. no. The function $\int \frac{1-x}{x W(\frac{1-x}{x})}\,dx$ is not the inverse function of $\int \frac{dx}{x\log x+1}$, but $\frac{1-x}{x W(\frac{1-x}{x})}$ is the inverse function of $\frac{1}{1+x\log x}$. In particular the integral above is just as difficult as $\int\frac{dx}{1+x\log x}$, since $$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = b f(b)-a f(a)$$ if $f(x)$ is increasing on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio is it possible to know or tell what exactly is the inverse function of $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x\ln\left(x\right)+1}$ ?

Comment: It can be written in terms of the derivative of the inverse function. Anyway, the mildly interesting fact here is just that $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x\log x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Notice that, in the real domain, the integrand is limited to the range $0 < x \leq \frac{e}{e-1}$.

Comment: If you need more coefficients for the expansion around $x=1$, a few are given by $$\left\{\frac{119}{5760},-\frac{44297}{45360},-\frac{178361}{403200},-\frac{930163}{
   570240},-\frac{65306461}{43545600},-\frac{67017757}{20756736},-\frac{27018542629
   }{6706022400}\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you change variable $$\frac{1-x}x=t\implies x=\frac{1}{t+1}\implies dx=-\frac{dt}{(t+1)^2}$$ you end with 
$$I=\int \frac{1-x}{x W\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)} \, dx=-\int \frac {t}{(1+t^2) \, W(t)} \,dt$$ You can expand the integrand around $t=0$ using composition of Taylor series. This would give
$$ \frac {t}{(1+t^2) \, W(t)}=1-t+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{2 }{3}t^3-\frac{71 }{24}t^4+\frac{443 }{60}t^5-\frac{11627
   }{720}t^6+\frac{86111 }{2520}t^7+O\left(t^8\right)$$

**Edit**

Thinking more about it, using Taylor around $x=1$, you have
$$\frac{1-x}{x W\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)} =1-(x-1)+\frac{1}{2} (x-1)^2-\frac{2}{3} (x-1)^3+\frac{3}{8} (x-1)^4-\frac{19}{30}
   (x-1)^5+\frac{35}{144} (x-1)^6-\frac{601}{840} (x-1)^7+O\left((x-1)^8\right)$$

Integrating between $\frac 12$ and $\frac 32$,the above series would lead to $\frac{48241}{46080}\approx 1.0468967$ while the numerical integration would give $1.0467994$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $u=\dfrac{1-x}{x}$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{1}{u+1}$

$dx=-\dfrac{du}{(u+1)^2}$

$\therefore\int\dfrac{1-x}{xW\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)}~dx=-\int\dfrac{u}{(u+1)^2W(u)}~du$

Let $v=W(u)$ ,

Then $u=ve^v$

$du=(v+1)e^v~dv$

$\therefore-\int\dfrac{u}{(u+1)^2W(u)}~du=-\int\dfrac{(v+1)e^{2v}}{(ve^v+1)^2}~dv$